# SELECT all records that match one value but don't exist with another

Tags: sql

I'm trying to select all IDs that have a 'passed' but do not have a 'failed' status in another record. Obviously ID is not a primary key for this table.  But this does not work (it only looks at a given record not all records)  I think I need some sort of aggregate function?

SELECT ID FROM TABLE
WHERE STATUS = "passed" AND STATUS != "failed"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try the following^

```
SELECT ID FROM TABLE WHERE STATUS = 'passed'
EXCEPT
SELECT ID FROM TABLE WHERE STATUS = 'failed'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation:

```
select id
from table
where status in ('passed', 'failed')
group by id
having min(status) = 'passed';
```

This uses the fact that `'passed' < 'failed'` for the `having` clause.  If the min is "passed", then all are "passed".

Comment: Will work no matter what the strings are?  It will return the records of the having statement no matter what other strings are in the IN statement? As long as a record exists with each value in the IN?